# Website Content disappearing behind fixed navbar with margin-top when scrolling

Tags: html, css, margin, fixed

I'm trying to build a fixed navbar with a margin-top on top of a website which has a background texture.
I'd like the content of the website to be hidden but the navbar when scrolling down but I want to keep this empty margin-top the all time.
Here is the over simple html:

```
<nav>
    My Fixed navbar with margin on top
</nav>
<div id="content">
    My content that shouldn't apppear in the margin-top of the navbar
</div>
```

I have made a jfiddle to explain my problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/nicoj/ttL3mp4r/8/

Basically the content is hiding behind the navbar when scrolling down which is cool but is reappearing above it after...

What I would like to do is to prevent the content from reappearing above the navbar: Keeping the navbar and the background image on top the whole time.
I was thinking of having the #content fixed too with an overflow: scroll but then the scrollbar is embedded inside the content which I don't want.

I feel like I'm missing something simple here...
I hope you have any tips!

Nico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the fact that your background is fixed as well, there's a pretty quick and easy way to solve this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="overlay">  
</div>
<nav>
    fixed navbar
</nav>
<div id="content">
    My content that should not appear above the navbar
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#overlay {
   position: fixed;
    background-image: url("http://allroundnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/seamless-wood-texture-free-76.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    top: -20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ttL3mp4r/14/)

I'm sure there are better ways to solve this, but this seemed like an easy fix for a simple issue.

Comment: Of course... I was looking for the big gun solution but this is cool.
Cheers !